# Same Chrome versions, same AdBlock versions, same AdBlock settings, YouTube has ads only on Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, youtube, adblock

I just did a fresh Mac OS install (Sierra) on a new SSD and installed Google Chrome and [AdBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom).

I noticed I see YouTube ads on it.

I updated my Windows 10 PC to the same version of Chrome and compared the AdBlock settings on both. I quit and restarted Chrome on both machines.

The PC still doesn't get YouTube ads and the Mac still does get them.

Googling, I can't find other people with a similar problem. What might I have done wrong?

Comment: Is HOSTS file the same? Are they both using the same DNS server? Are the exception lists in AdBlock the same?

Comment: I've never editing any of those things on either machine so they should be the same. But I'll check it all out and get back...